# Which mirror to select for iinet freezone usage

Tags: updates, iso, mirrors, stable-release-updates

Where can I select the [iinet mirror](https://wiki.edubuntu.org/AustralianTeam/LocalAptMirrors#iiNet.2BAC8-OzEmail_Mirror) in Australia for my Ubuntu installation?

iinet offers a *off quota* access to [linux images](http://ftp.iinet.net.au/linux/) and also an [mirror](http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/).

Going through the server list on my Ubuntu 14.04 installation does not list any iinet mirrors. [image: list of Australian mirrors]

Note: When searching for iinet mirror I found a [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ftp.iinet.net.au-archive) site listing iinet.

Note 2: I'm also unsure if the internote mirror is a combined mirror and quota free for iinet users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the link manually. To do this open a terminal and run the following command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Now, comment out the entries by placing `#` in front of the lines. Add the following lines (do not put `#` in-front of this line!):

```
deb http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu/ <YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE> main
```

Replace `<YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE>` with the one you are using. e.g.: if you are using 14.04, put `trusty` there.

Now, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> , type `Y` to confirm and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`